# Inner delayed expansion in a batch script (windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

I need to make delayed expansion inside of delayed expansion, i.e. smth like:

```
!PARAMS[!BEFORE_LAST!]!
```

Of course, the above is not valid, so I tried to workaround it with for-loop, but with no success:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET PARAM_COUNT=0
FOR %%P IN (%*) DO (
    SET /A PARAM_COUNT+=1
    SET PARAMS[!PARAM_COUNT!]=%%P

    IF !PARAM_COUNT! GTR 1 (
        SET /A BEFORE_LAST = !PARAM_COUNT!-1
        FOR /L %%G IN (!BEFORE_LAST!) DO SET BEFORE_LAST_PARAM=!PARAMS[%%G]!
        IF "!BEFORE_LAST_PARAM!"=="--buildroot" (
            REM perfrom some actions here
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

How could I achieve the explained behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delayed expansion` inside `delayed expansion` doesn't work, try this:

```
CALL SET "myvar=%%PARAMS[!BEFORE_LAST!]%%"
```

Comment: Hey Endoro. Eventually it rocked. Firstly %%PARAMS got confused with my loop variable %%P. But then I renamed my loop variable and it got much better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much of an answer, but using @Enduro's Answer, I solved my problem. I am just giving an example here, to see how to use it.

This answer was the only one that worked for me! After a LOT of searching; Basically I was trying to generate a file with all android app package names, without version codes. We have used a gradle script to generate names in a particular format also, something like:  `com.package.appname-releaseVersion.apk`.

Here is the original code for generating file (apps.ls) with required package names, which I mainly use like this, inside android shell: `for app in $(cat < apps.ls ); do monkey -p $app 1; done;`. It just launches all those apps to make sure their services start running and registered.

### My Original Script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\remoteUpdate"

>apps.ls (
    for /r %%v in (*.apk) do (
        set "name=%%~nv"
        call :indexof "!name!" "-" idx
        call echo %%name:~0,!!idx!!%%
    )
)

C:\dos2unix\bin\dos2unix.exe apps.ls

@echo Done generating apps.ls


:indexof [%1 - string ; %2 - find index of ; %3 - if defined will store the result in variable with same name]
::http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1687
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "str=%~1"
set "s=!str:%~2=&rem.!"
set s=#%s%
if "%s%" equ "#%~1" endlocal& if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=-1&exit /b 0) else (echo -1&exit /b 0) 

  set "len=0"
  for %%A in (2187 729 243 81 27 9 3 1) do (
    set /A mod=2*%%A
    for %%Z in (!mod!) do (
        if "!s:~%%Z,1!" neq "" (
            set /a "len+=%%Z"
            set "s=!s:~%%Z!"
            
        ) else (
            if "!s:~%%A,1!" neq "" (
                set /a "len+=%%A"
                set "s=!s:~%%A!"
            )
        )
    )
  )
  endlocal & if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=%len%)
exit /b 0
```

Now the issue was that I needed to filter out certain packages out of my `apps.ls` file,

### Changes

All I needed to do was change the code inside the for loop like so:

```
    CALL SET "truncname=%%name:~0,!!idx!!%%"
    if NOT "!truncname!"=="com.blhealthcare.package1" if NOT "!truncname!"=="com.android.package2" echo !truncname!
```

Everything I tried before that, using only *set* was not working. However using call with set worked really well. I cannot find any documentation on this as well, as it's difficult to even search this issue. What I noticed was that `call echo %%name:~0,!!idx!!%%` was printing correctly, whereas `echo %%name:~0,!!idx!!%%` was printing something like `name:~0,28` and not working. I couldn't understand it then, but today I can understand from @Endoro's answer that

> `delayed expansion` inside `delayed expansion` doesn't work